# Fragment Custom Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, slide

I have 2 fragments say Fragment A and Fragment B. i need to animate fragment A and B when moving back and forth.

Animation Behavior looking for :
When moving - Retain Fragment A and then slide fragment B on top of Fragment A from right.(not to push fragment A)

How i can achieve this ?  i have read few posts but all says slide in and out animation.

```
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) mContext;
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
FragmentB fragment = (FragmentB ) Fragment
                .instantiate(fragmentActivity,
                        FragmentB .class.getName(), extras);
ft.addToBackStack(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment,
                FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe implementing a ViewPager will solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: No i cannot use this :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing, try to add FragmentB

```
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) mContext;
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
FragmentB fragment = (FragmentB ) Fragment
                .instantiate(fragmentActivity,
                        FragmentB .class.getName(), extras);
ft.addToBackStack(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
ft.add(R.id.frame, fragment,
                FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: if we add instead of replace then we need to also remove the fragment each time if i am correct

Comment: No you dont need it as you are adding it in backstack, "add" will only place a fragment in the top of the lower fragment, and when any back event occur it will simply get out from the screen and the lower fragment gets appearing. The only thing here is when the Second Fragment Pop out, you will not get any callback in any method of your First Fragment, until you have some explicit call (using interface etc)

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure but having no out animation may work. (I haven't tried this)

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, 0);
```